# Printf function formatter

Tags: c++, integer, printf, overflow, implicit-conversion

Having following simple C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c1 = 130;
    unsigned char c2 = 130;

    printf("1: %+u\n", c1);
    printf("2: %+u\n", c2);
    printf("3: %+d\n", c1);
    printf("4: %+d\n", c2);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

the output is like that:

```
1: 4294967170
2: 130
3: -126
4: +130
```

Can someone please explain me the line 1 and 3 results?

I'm using Linux `gcc` compiler with all default settings.

Comment: This is called overflow.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? (i.e., adding the `#include`s and `main`?)

Comment: @L.F. Not by the standard ... in which "overflow" refers to an arithmetic operation producing a result out of bounds for its type

Comment: The concept of overflow is explained here; [C++ integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235436/c-integer-overflow). The `char` is represented on 8 bits

Comment: Looks more like C code to me.

Comment: [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function reads arguments by [va_arg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) from stack according to the format specified in the first argument string. I.e. if you have %u - it means read 4 bytes (unsigned int) from the top of the stack. You've put only one byte into stack - as well as result is undefined. Try to `printf("1: %+u\n", (unsigned int)c1);` and `printf("3: %+d\n", (int)c1);` 2. Range for `signed char type` is -127...+ 128

Comment: It's C++ as long as it's compiled as C++.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is 8 bits. This means it can represent 2^8=256 unique values. A `uchar` represents 0 to 255, and a signed `char` represents -128 to 127 (could represent absolutely anything, but this is the typical platform implementation). Thus, assigning 130 to a  `char` is out of range by 2, and the value overflows and wraps the value to -126 when it is **interpreted** as a signed `char`. The compiler sees 130 as an integer and makes an implicit conversion from `int` to `char`. On most platforms an int is 32-bit and the sign bit is the MSB, the value 130 easily fits into the first 8-bits, but then the compiler wants to chop of 24 bits to squeeze it into a char. When this happens, and you've told the compiler you want a signed char, the MSB of the first 8 bits actually represents -128. Uh oh! You have this in memory now `1000 0010`, which when interpreted as a signed char is -128+2. My linter on my platform screams about this . .

[image: angry linter]

I make that important point about interpretation because in memory, both values are identical. You can confirm this by casting the value in the `printf` statements, i.e., `printf("3: %+d\n", (unsigned char)c1);`, and you'll see 130 again.

The reason you see the large value in your first `printf` statement is that you are casting a signed `char` to an unsigned `int`, where the `char` has already overflowed. The machine **interprets** the `char` as -126 first, and then casts to unsigned `int`, which cannot represent that negative value, so you get the max value of the signed `int` and subtract 126.

2^32-126 = 4294967170 . . bingo

In `printf` statement 2, all the machine has to do is add 24 zeros to reach 32-bit, and then interpret the value as `int`. In statement one, you've told it that you have a signed value, so it first turns that to a 32-bit -126 value, and then interprets that -ve integer as an unsigned integer. Again, it flips how it interprets the most significant bit. There are 2 steps:

1. Signed char is promoted to signed int, because you want to work with ints. The char (is probably copied and) has 24 bits added. Because we're looking at a signed value, some machine instruction will happen to perform twos complement, so the memory here looks quite different.
2. The new signed int memory is interpreted as unsigned, so the machine looks at the MSB and interprets it as 2^32 instead of -2^31 as happened in the promotion.

An interesting bit of trivia, is you can suppress the clang-tidy linter warning if you do `char c1 = 130u;`, but you still get the same garbage based on the above logic (i.e. the implicit conversion throws away the first 24-bits, and the sign-bit was zero anyhow). I'm have submitted an LLVM clang-tidy missing functionality report based on exploring this question (issue [42137](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42137) if you really wanna follow it) .

Comment: It would be nice if you mention that this is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @L.F. it isn't UB (unless you mean incorrect format specifiers)

Comment: @learnvst Ok, can You explain how does the wrap is made? And  what about the line #1: 4294967170 value?

Comment: @Daros - sorry, cleaned that answer up a little further

Comment: @M.M After some research, I found out that `char(130)` is implementation-defined behavior instead of UB. Take my comment to mean the incorrect format specifiers ;-)

Comment: @learnvst So in case #3 (-126) the value -126 is produced by applying 2-complements on 130?

Comment: @Daros. It is not applying any form of algorithm. You are just telling the machine to interpret those 8 bits in memory as a signed value, therefore, it takes the most significant bit, and interprets that as -128 and adds 2, rather than interpreting is as 128 and adding 2

Comment: @Daros - I also appended that to the answer itself

Comment: @learnvst In Your's answer (first sentence in #3 paragraph) "...you are casting a signed char to a signed int..." shouldn't rather be "casting a signed chat to an UNSIGNED int" as "u" specifier tells?

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes that, on your machine, `char` ranges from -128 to 127, that `unsigned char` ranges from 0 to 255, and that `unsigned int` ranges from 0 to 4294967295, which happens to be the case.)

```
char c1 = 130;
```

Here, 130 is outside the range of numbers representable by `char`. The value of `c1` is implementation-defined. In your case, the number happens to "wrap around," initializing `c1` to `static_cast<char>(-126)`.

In

```
printf("1: %+u\n", c1);
```

`c1` is promoted to `int`, resulting in `-126`. Then, it is interpreted by the `%u` specifier as `unsigned int`. This is undefined behavior. This time the resulting number happens to be the unique number representable by `unsigned int` that is congruent to -126 modulo 4294967296, which is 4294967170.

In

```
printf("3: %+d\n", c1);
```

The `int` value `-126` is interpreted by the `%d` specifier as `int` directly, and outputs -126 as expected (?).

Comment: @eerorika I just realized how wrong I have been. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In cases 1, 2 the format specifier doesn't match the type of the argument, so the behaviour of the program is undefined (on most systems). On most systems `char` and `unsigned char` are smaller than `int`, so they promote to int when passed as variadic arguments. `int` doesn't match the format specifier `%u` which requires `unsigned int`.

On exotic systems (which your target is not) where `unsigned char` is as large as `int`, it will be promoted to `unsigned int` instead, in which case 4 would have UB since it requires an `int`.

---

Explanation for 3 depends a lot on implementation specified details. The result depends on whether `char` is signed or not, and it depends on the representable range.

If 130 was a representable value of `char`, such as when it is an unsigned type, then 130 would be the correct output. That appears to not be the case, so we can assume that `char` is a signed type on the target system.

Initialising a signed integer with an unrepresentable value (such as `char` with 130 in this case) results in an implementation defined value.

On systems with 2's complement representation for signed numbers - which is ubiquitous representation these days - the implementation defined value is typically the representable value that is congruent with the unrepresentable value modulo the number of representable values. -126 is congruent with 130 modulo 256 and is a representable value of `char`.