# Cast from int to char

Tags: c++

I'd like to know how this cast works :

```
int value = 100;
auto f = [&value] (int x, int y) -> char { return x + y + value; };
printf("%d\n", f(10, 20));
value = 200;
printf("%d\n", f(10, 20));
return 0;
```

It prints -126 and -30 but i don't understand how is it possible to print a negative integer.

Comment: Read your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Take a peek at my answer to a very related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56424762/276193

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned. If it is signed, overflow has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Change `char` to `unsigned char` if you want to represent 0 .. 255.

Comment: There are no casts in this code. The question seems to be about a **conversion**. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion l

Answer (score 0):

The numerical range for `char` is `-128`..`127`. `10 + 20 + 100` is `130` and outside of that range, so it wraps around when expressed as `char`.

To fix you need to use a data type that can contain values large enough:

```
auto f = [&value] (int x, int y) -> int { return x + y + value; };
```

Or use values < 127.

Comment: it's an example from my OOP course, not some code written by me. Can you please explain the calculation such that the example lead to -126 and -30? I didn't really understand how it "wraps" around

Comment: Signed integer numbers in modern machines are stored in [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). An 8-bit value (`char`) can either be unsigned (`0`..`255`) or signed with Two's Complement (`-128`..`127`). No other values can be represented. In the case of signed, `char x = 127 + 1` assigns `-128` to `x`. In your case, 130 is precisely 3 over the limit, so it's the same as `127 + 3` where that's `-126` wrapped around.