# Is pointer better in compute?

Tags: c++

I found a code which introducing to the pointers, and was a creating copy of swap function using pointers but i don't know what is better using pointers or using common variables.

swap using pointers:

```
int a = 10, b = 20, *p1 = &a, *p2 = &b;
*p1 = *p1 + *p2;
*p2 = *p1 - *p2;
*p1 = *p1 - *p2;
std::cout << a << " " << *p1 << " " << b << " " << *p2 << std::endl;
```

and swap using common variables:

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

which of these is better using?

Comment: None of these are any good as `a + b` could overflow, use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead.

Comment: Surely you can count that the pointer version does 9 indirections that the other version doesn’t?

Comment: Even if you need to implement is "manually" (instead of `std::swap`) there's no reason to use pointers here.

Comment: I can't think of a possible reason that you could get the impression that the first version might be better. Why do you consider it possible to that it might be better? But as mentioned above, both of them are wrong anyway (if the values of `a` and `b` aren't fixed to the ones in the example).

Comment: You can use [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7MdaWzzsP) to check the assemblies. Of course they have no differences at all, because compiler is very smart. However, both versions are not recommended because of possible overflow. Even if you can use methods like xor to avoid overflow problems, it does not make sense at all. Do use `std::swap` or use a temp variable to perform swap, unless you are doing some strange homework requiring no temp variables.

Comment: swapping pointers is a low level technique originating from "C" that may be faster when you want to sort (larger) structs. However with current C++ it is more common to rely on move semantics and `std::swap`. C++ is kind of moving away from using raw pointers, see: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines. The (regrettable) fact is that there is just so much legacy code and legacy training material out there so it is easy to pickup "unsafe" techniques from the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an unimportant detail. Do whatever you think is most readable for you.

Compiler authors are really smart. So, after enabling optimization, all versions of your code would produce exactly the same outcome (machine code).

Here is a demo: https://godbolt.org/z/cWWo4G1T8

For this code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void foo(int a, int b);

void demo1(int a, int b)
{
    int *p1 = &a, *p2 = &b;
    *p1 = *p1 + *p2;
    *p2 = *p1 - *p2;
    *p1 = *p1 - *p2;
    foo(a, b);
}

void demo2(int a, int b)
{
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
    foo(a, b);
}

void demo3(int a, int b)
{
    std::swap(a,b);
    foo(a, b);
}

void demo4(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
    foo(a, b);
}
```

Compiler produces:

```
demo1(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     edi, esi
        mov     esi, eax
        jmp     foo(int, int)
demo2(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     edi, esi
        mov     esi, eax
        jmp     foo(int, int)
demo3(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     edi, esi
        mov     esi, eax
        jmp     foo(int, int)
demo4(int, int):
        mov     eax, edi
        mov     edi, esi
        mov     esi, eax
        jmp     foo(int, int)
```

So, all four versions are giving exactly same result.

I would recommend using `std::swap`, since the intent is clearer.

This thing is possible since all compiler are using the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Basically, the compiler has the right to do any kind of transformation of your code so long as all visible effects of execution remain unchanged. Thus, the compiler is able to get rid of lots of boiler-plate code.

Comment: This is excellent

Answer (score 2):

> [I] was a creating copy of swap function.

So, instead of the posted snippet, let's see what it would happen if the OP would have written an *actual* function taking two pointers:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

void p_swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    *p1 = *p1 + *p2;
    *p2 = *p1 - *p2;
    *p1 = *p1 - *p2;
}

void r_swap(int &a, int &b)
{ //            ^       ^   Note the references.
    std::swap(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 25;
    assert(a == 10  and  b == 25);  // Of course...

    p_swap(&a, &b);
    assert(a == 25  and  b == 10);  // OK. So far, so good...

    p_swap(&a, &a);
    //      ^   ^     It MIGHT happen in real code.

    //assert(a == 25);   // <--- It FAILS! Kind of unexpected, but:
    assert(a == 0);      //  25 + 25 = 50, 50 - 50 = 0, 0 - 0 = 0

    a = 25;              // Let's try it again.
    r_swap(a, a);
    assert(a == 25);     // Good job.
}
```

In the comments was also mentioned the risk of Undefined Behavior<sup>1</sup> due to possible integer overflows<sup>2</sup> during the operations, unlike [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) (or [`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)).

It's worth mentioning that the actual<sup>3</sup> generated assembly is quite different from `std::swap`:

```
p_swap(int*, int*):                          # @p_swap(int*, int*)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        add     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        sub     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        sub     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        ret
r_swap(int&, int&):                     # @r_swap(int&, int&)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], ecx
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

**EDIT**

I received a comment suggesting the use of [`__restrict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c) to allow more aggressive compiler optimizations. It "works"<sup>4</sup>, but the price is more Undefined Behavior (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/d37ecx4qs).

---

<sup>1. See e.g. [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) or [cppreference.com page about UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)</sup>
<sup>2. See e.g. [C++ integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235436/c-integer-overflow)</sup>
<sup>3. Compiler explorer demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7zEzP4hWd</sup>
<sup>4. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/4Tqjsb3r1</sup>